# Post's "Read More" redirects to wrong post

Tags: posts

I have a page on my website with a grid of posts. They are ascending in alphabetical order.

One particular post, that was most recently added, links to the next post in alphabetical order. It also takes that post's place in on the "posts" page. I cannot figure out why.

For instance...

[post a] [post b] [post d]

Post b links to what should be post c.

If I make post b a draft, everything works fine again.

Here is the weirdest part... If I edit the next in line post (alphabetically) that post disappears too. I've edited the next three posts and now those three aren't showing up. And [post b] now links to next in line. So strange...

Here is a list of the posts on the page in Wordpress Admin:
[image]

Here is how it renders:
[image]

Unfortunately I can't post links to the website.

Comment: Please add the query code, which retrives the posts. Otherwise it is just guessing into the dark. Thanks

Comment: I didn't do a query. It is being done by some Masonry plugin but the plugin isn't at fault because I have the same issue with multiple plugins that I've tested.

Comment: Then the best way is to contact the plugin owner/builder - we can't know what's going on without a single line of code. He/she is responsible for the output - hence he/she will be able to help you best.